# PHP: changing the variable inside the class

Tags: php, json, class

I'm working on a class and I'm trying to output it using json_encode but the variable won't change.

PHP:

```
<?php

class person { 
    public $person = "";
}
class name {
    public $lastname = "";
    public $firstname  = "";
}

$user = new person();
$user->person = new name();

$user->lastname = "Foo";
$user->firstname  = "Bar";

echo json_encode($user);
?>
```

OUTPUT:

> {"person":{"lastname":"","firstname":""},"lastname":"Foo","firstname":"Bar"}

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

> {"person":{"lastname":Foo"","firstname":"Bar"}}

can someone explain to me why it wont change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set the `$user`'s name shouldn't you be calling:

```
$user->person->firstname = "Foo";
$user->person->lastname  = "Bar";
```

Alternatively you could also set the variables of `name` before setting it in the `person`

```
$name = new name();
$name->firstname = "Foo";
$name->lastname  = "Bar";

$user->person = $name;
```

EDIT

If you only want a single class and you want to replicate your expected output:

```
class person {
    public $firstname;
    public $lastname;
}

$user = new person();

$user->firstname = "Foo";
$user->lastname  = "Bar";

echo json_encode(array('person' => $user));
```

Comment: Or he could just extend the class if he really wants to use `$user->firstname` which makes more sense semantically.

Comment: is there any way to shorten the class with the same output? like I just want to put them in 1 class?

Comment: Yes, you can simply have a single `person` class with two variables `$firstname` and `$lastname`

Comment: can you provide me a example

Comment: i dont want to used array in the code. is there any way for that?

Comment: @sa.lva.ge I'm sorry, I don't think I understand what you're trying to achieve. If my answer is unclear please update your question with more detail so we have a better understanding. As far as your current question is concerned, all of the answers provided solve your problem.

Comment: i mean like is there any other way to generate without using a class?

Answer (score 0):

Change these lines

```
$user->lastname = "Foo";
$user->firstname  = "Bar";
```

To

```
$user->person->lastname = "Foo";
$user->person->firstname  = "Bar";
```

You never assign these properties, that's why they're empty in your string. Instead, you assign them to the `user`, instead of the `name`, and that's why you are seeing them after the encoded `name`.
Stricly spoken, this should not be allowed to work, and you should get a STRICT warning.

Comment: is there any way to shorten the class with the same output? like I just want to put them in 1 class?

Answer (score 0):

The `name` class is assigned to `$user->person`.

So when you assigning values for `firesname` and `lastname` in your `name` class, you should use below code

```
$user->person->lastname="Foo";
$user->person->firstname="Bar";
```

or

The `firstname` and `lastname` variable in `name` class are consider as new data